# jQuery or angularjs plugin to build dynamic reports

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, report

I'm looking for some sort of drag and drop  jquery/angular/javascript plugin that can create dynamic report.

The type of report I want to create is not charts but simple tables and grids with texts . After creating this I could be able to download it as pdf or excel file. Basically I want to create pdf or excel reports.

Could not find anything after lots of googling. I hope someone knows of something that can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to pay for it but the best plugin I've seen for this type of stuff is the Telerik Kendo UI Grid.

Check it out here:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Comment: Thanks,Ya its looks good . Do you also know anything which is open source ?